# How to program a function whose return value is depending on the flag without using "if"?

Tags: c++, boolean, conditional-operator, function-definition

I want to make a class function like the conceptual code below.

```
double function(){
  if(flag==true){
    "some process and return "
  } 
  else{
    "another process and return"
  }
}
```

where `flag` is the boolean member of the class.
I want to make this function without using  `if` because I use this function many times.
The points are

1. I want to use the same function with the two cases of the process.
2. I want to avoid re-evaluation of a flag that doesn't change its value for some period.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I edited the question for the more clear explanation of the problem. The process is much more complicated in reality.

Comment: It seems like you want to avoid re-evaluation of a flag that doesn't change its value for some period of time (which you didn't tell us)?

Comment: How many more times will you edit the question? Can't you use two classes, one for the flag being `true` and another for `false`?  Can you specify  any guarantees about  "flag that doesn't change its value for some period of time"? Finally, testing a boolean flag is usually so quick, especially if the variable is cached, that the processor does not even notice it. Look somewhere elese for optimization, or at least do some performance tests!

Comment: You could add an observer to the flag and call the right process  with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call one of two different member functions depending on the value of a `bool` without using an `if` or something else that might lead to branching, you could create a table containing two function pointers and use that for lookup by using the `bool` for indexing. If you only want to do this lookup when the value of the flag changes, you could store a pointer to the *active* function and only do the lookup when `flag` is set.

Example where the member functions are also taking an argument:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
public:
    using func_t = double(foo::*)(double); // the type of the member functions

    double some(double x) { return x * 3.14159; }
    double another(double x) { return x * 3.14159 * 3.14159; }

    double function(double x) {      
        return (this->*active)(x); // "active" only changes when "flag" is set
    }

    void set(bool x) {
        flag = x;
        // lookup without "if" to set the active function:
        active = funcs[flag];
    }

private:
    // a static table of the functions to be called - only initialized once
    static constexpr func_t funcs[]{&foo::some, &foo::another};

    bool flag = false;
    func_t active = &foo::some;     // the active function
};

int main() {
    foo x;

    x.set(false);
    std::cout << x.function(2.) << '\n';

    x.set(true);
    std::cout << x.function(3.) << '\n';    
}
```

Output

```
6.28318
29.6088
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching your beautiful method.
Could you tell me  where to fix when "some" and "another" have arguments, such as "double some(double const& x) { return x; }"?

Comment: @kfukai You're welcome. I've edited the answer. I made it take a `double` instead of a `double const&` though. Shouldn't matter I hope :-)

Comment: If I understood, you ar using a boolean as index, that doens't look so nice, maybe some cast would make it pretier ? :)

Comment: @Ivan That's not needed. As I mentioned in a comment to another answer: A `bool` will be implicitly promoted to `int` with the value 0 (`false`) or 1 (`true`) in this context so a cast doesn't really provide anything meaningful. I noticed the smiley. Perhaps you read my comment regarding this? :-)

Comment: Just a quick warning to readers: replacing a boolean check with a function pointer based redirection is unlikely to improve overall performance. Nothing wrong with the answer if the motivation is anything other than performance gains ;)

Comment: @grek40 Testing is always key. In many cases the compiler will likely be able to "see" that checking `flag` before a loop, for example, and instead create two separate loops without `if`, will be faster. The function pointer may become quicker if a) the optimizer isn't able to do that kind of optimization and b) the state of `flag` changes rarely. I would personally go for the simplest solution first and try out different "hand-optimizations" like this one later. ... and test test test.

Comment: I made two tests (not in a presentable condition right now). If the compiler _is_ able to do the optimization mentioned and `flag` changes state 1/100, the `if` is equally fast as using the function pointer. If the compiler is _not_ able to do the optimization mentioned, using the function pointer is 3.2 times faster (with the same number of state changes). If the state changes often (every time), the `if` is 3.8 times faster than the function pointer. These are preliminary results using quick-bench. So, testing for the particular situation is really key to see if there is a gain or not.

Answer (score 2):

Class function, flag, and two different behaviors? You probably should make two derived classes, drop the flag, and use a `virtual` function instead.

Comment: I guess OP wants to be able to change the state of the object at will and then to perform different actions depending on its state, and want to do it very quickly, so quickly that the test be omitted.  In other word: to my understanding OP asks for the impossible. So, basically, you subbmitted an   answer to an ill-posed question. If OP actually wants to be able to change his object's state at any moment, virtual functions are no solution to a problem that has no solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can just cast the boolean into an int

```
int test(bool flag)
{
    return static_cast<int>(flag);
}

int not_test(bool flag)
{
    return static_cast<int>(!flag);
}
```

Remark: By the time this answer was posted, the question was completely different.

Comment: [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) say: "_Integral promotion: The type `bool` can be converted to `int` with the value `false` becoming ​`0`​ and `true` becoming `1`_" - so the cast isn't necessary.

Comment: So you downvoted because I explicitely casted? As far as I learned, you should always make things clear and avoid implicit casts.

Comment: I haven't downvoted _any_ answer to this question - I just mentioned that the cast you suggest isn't needed because of integer promotion - like when assigning a `short` to an `int`. People rarely cast when doing that either.